# Start Inno Setup installer without "This will install .... Do you wish to continue?" prompt

Tags: inno-setup

When I run my Inno Setup script, I get the prompt *"This will install .... Do you wish to continue?"*.

How could it be done so that the installation starts without this prompt.

The user already double clicked the setup to install it, then an UAC event occurs, and then Inno Setup asks the user if he really wants to install the application.

This makes the user look really dumb, he has to "confirm" three times.

Is there a way to skip the last prompt?

This is my script:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion=
AppName=MyApp
AppVerName=MyApp 
AppPublisher=MyCompanyName
AppPublisherURL=www.mywebsite.com
AppSupportURL=www.mywebsite.com
AppUpdatesURL=www.mywebsite.com
AppID=A1T2B24E-304A-2274-5A2A-550GF09E4712
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
DefaultGroupName=MyApp
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
LicenseFile=
SetupIconFile=d:\dev\projects\distribute\box_software.ico
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=admin
WizardImageFile=d:\dev\projects\innosetup\large.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=d:\dev\projects\innosetup\small.bmp
DirExistsWarning=no
UsePreviousAppDir=yes
ShowLanguageDialog=auto
SignedUninstaller=yes
SignedUninstallerDir=d:\dev\projects\innosetup\signeduninstaller
OutputBaseFilename=osb_setup_update
OutputDir=d:\dev\projects\MyApp\compiled\upload
```

Edit: Dispite having defined `DisableReadyPage`, I still get this certain page.

This is a screenshot:

[image]

The translation to English would be *"Ready for installation"*. Setup is now ready to install the app to the computer. Click Install to start the installation."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That prompt is disabled by default. If you see it, you must have [`DisableStartupPrompt`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablestartupprompt) set to `no`. Set it to `yes`, or remove it altogether (`yes` is default).

```
[Setup]
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
```